# Is it possible to evaluate a String with a double regular expression (regex) in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm trying to evaluate a String against two simultaneous patterns in a personal ID text field (Fig. 1):

[image: Fig. 1]

This field is intended for the user to input his personal Spanish (DNI) OR Portuguese (Cartão de cidadão) national identification number, and the idea is to evaluate both patterns at once, not caring about the locale set (the website is in Spanish, English and Portuguese).

Those patterns should be:

1. Spanish: `/^[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET]{1}$/i` (i.e. 12345678A)
2. Portuguese: `/^[0-9]{7,8}\[0-9]\([A-Z]|[0-9]){2}[0-9]$/` (i.e. 04521225)

With this, the code snippet of the form is as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="field_dni"
    class="form-control form-control-400" id="field_dni"
    ng-model="vm.form.dni" 
    ng-minlength=9 
    ng-maxlength=9 
    ng-pattern= "vm.verificarId" />
<div ng-show="verificarForm.field_dni.$invalid">
    <p class="help-block"
        ng-show="verificarForm.field_dni.$error.pattern"
        translate="verificar.validation.pattern">The pattern entered is 
        incorrect
    </p>    
    <p class="help-block"
        ng-show="verificarForm.field_dni.$error.required"
        translate="verificar.validation.required">This field is required.
    /p>
    <p class="help-block"
        ng-show="verificarForm.field_dni.$error.minlength"
        translate="verificar.validation.minlength">This field is required to 
        be exactly 9 characters long
    </p>        
    <p class="help-block"
        ng-show="verificarForm.field_dni.$error.maxlength"
        translate="verificar.validation.maxlength">This field is required to 
        be exactly 9 characters long
    </p>
```

As you can see, what should happen is that every validation (length and pattern) are evaluated.

The relevant controller snippet looks like this:

```
function ValidateController($scope, Principal, ValidateService,  $state) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.verificarId= /^[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET]{1}$/i|/^[0-9]{7,8}\[0-9]\([A-Z]|[0-9]){2}[0-9]$/;
```

This does not work. The pattern seems to be ignored. I have tried putting parentheses between the two regexp conditions, such as:

```
/(^[0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET]{1}$/i)|(/^[0-9]{7,8}\[0-9]\([A-Z]|[0-9]){2}[0-9]$)/
```

But throws a syntax error. **The only way I have managed to get this partially working** is hardcoding either one regExp or the another into the ng-pattern component. But this is not optimal, as both need to be working together.

Is there a better and "Angularier" way of doing this? I have tried to rebuild the regex again in regex101, with no success.

Comment: Try `/^([0-9]{8}[trwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcketTRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET]|[0-9]{7,8}\[0-9]\([A-Z]|[0-9]){2}[0-9])$/;`

Comment: Hi Wiktor, thanks for your comment,

Just tried your regex, and got this:

`Invalid regular expression: /^([0-9]{8}[trwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcketTRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET‌​]|[0-9]{7,8}\[0-9]\(‌​[A-Z]|[0-9]){2}[0-9]‌​)$/: Unmatched ')'`

Hunting down that rogue parenthesis, I managed to get the first condition working (12345678A), but not the second. Seems to be a syntax problem.

Comment: I just copied yours. So, find an issue on your side. Maybe your second one was [`^[0-9]{7,8}[0-9][A-Z0-9]{2}[0-9]$`](https://regex101.com/r/FrA28c/1)? Then your regex should look like [`^([0-9]{8}[trwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcketTRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKET]|[0-9]{7,8}[0-9][A-Z0-9]{2}[0-9])$`](https://regex101.com/r/ONPHJl/1). Do not copy paste from the comments, SO inserts garbage chars into these texts for better appearance.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Yes, I know. I wrote it one character at a time, but still can't get both working. Right now only one of the two works, and it seems to depend entirely on the placement of the expressions. The OR does not seem to be recognized.

Comment: Yes, it seems what you need cannot be done inside just one regex.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are using vm in the view. Assuming that you are using that controller in that view, the controller scope is the scope of the view, unless that you are using an alias

So you should be using `ng-pattern= "verificarId"`

instate of `ng-pattern= "vm.verificarId"`

Comment: Hi Gonzalo,

I tried your approach, but it's not working either. I tested printing the JSON as I filled the form, and with vm.verificarId I got this (pay attention to "form"):

`{
  "doNotMatch": null,
  "error": null,
  "errorUserExists": null,
  "registerAccount": {},
  "success": null,
  "dniValidate": null,
  "$resolve": {
    "$stateParams": {},
    
  },
  "form": {
    "dni": "123456789"
  }
}`

When I removed "vm", form did not even appear in the JSON log.